# What‘s the next step to solve this 10x10 nonogram?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, nonogram

I got stuck on this nonogram (picross) from the game “[Murder by Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_by_Numbers_(video_game))”:

[image: screenshot]

What is the next step from here?

Comment: It looks like in row 7, the third 2 is constrained.

Comment: Also, in row 7/8/9, the leftmost 2s in each row cannot all be satisfied in column 1, nor can they all be satisfied in column 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [comment by xnor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/125202/what-s-the-next-step-to-solve-this-10x10-nonogram#comment347737_125202), R7C9 has to be black. After filling this in, I was able to proceed and complete the puzzle. [Jeremy's hint](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/125202/what-s-the-next-step-to-solve-this-10x10-nonogram#comment347739_125202) also proved useful later on in the puzzle.